# Подскажите как сверстать такие секции

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите, как сверстать такие секции. Пробовал через clip-path обрезать блоки нужным образом, но при изменении разрешения clip-path обрезает уже не так, как нужно. Другой вариант, который был в голове, это ставить на фон уже готовую картинку такой формы и с помощью отступов соединять секции, чтобы закрыть зазоры между ними. При изменении ширины окна так же плохо себя ведет background-size: cover и картинка масштабируется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Смотри в сторону SVG

Answer (score 1):

Нарезать картинки примерно одинаковыми прямоуголниками[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

затем задать им по порядку:

```
body {
background: 
      url(1.png) 0 0 no-repeat,
      url(2.png) 0 200px no-repeat,
      #f3dbb3;
}
```